# Establish connection between PC and Mac

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, macbook-pro, file-sharing

I have a Windows PC which hosts all my important media and photos. I also recently bought a Macbook Pro. The former connects to the university network via Ethernet, and the latter via WiFi. I should point out that they have different IPs, which change from time to time. What would be the simplest way to create a network between those two computers? I have a lot of data that I need access to, and I don't necessarily want to download it all to my Macbook, just to access specific files from time to time. These files are too big for the cloud.

I tried sharing HDDs and folders on my Windows machine, but they were never discovered by my Mac. However, I managed to create an Ad-Hoc network on my PC, to which my Mac could connect and browse the shared files, but it was very slow and stopped working soon. Additionally, I have a few Ubuntu DigitalOcean VPSes at my disposal... only I don't really know how I could use them to establish a connection between my two machines.

Regards,

Nick.

Comment: By different IP's do you mean different networks? Can you find out the IP address and the subnet masks for each device? If they are on the same network I know a very easy way to access your Windows PC from your Mac.

Comment: @DrZoo When I'm connected via Ethernet on my PC, the IP begins like so: `5.1.x.x`, and I cannot access it from my Mac, but when I choose to connect via WiFi, both the PC and Mac share the same network address, like so: `134.225.x.x`, and the same subnet mask: `255.255.255.0`.

Comment: Neither of those are private IP address ranges, so that's confusing to me. What are you using to find out your IP address?

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought you meant something else. Here are the private IP addresses for the PC and Mac: 10.30.58.28, and 10.30.39.255, respectively.

Comment: @Nick - The best way to get this done is to purchase a Western Digital Cloud based storage for your home/dorm.  They sell 2TB to 24TB drives that will sit at your location and house all of your files and media.  You'll connect it to Ethernet and all your devices (laptop, phones, tablets) will have access to those files from anywhere.  This will free up storage on your PC and macbook.  I use it and I love it.  https://www.wdc.com/products/personal-cloud-storage/my-cloud.html

Comment: Do you know what the subnet mask is for those private IPs?

Comment: When I run ipconfig /all, it states that the subnet mask for my Windows private IP is 255.255.255.0, and for mac it's 255.255.248.0

Comment: Darn. Well you should be able to get around that if you were to buy a small cheap switch and you could plug both devices into that. I access my Windows PC from time to time with my Mac. You could also get your own WiFi router if the university allows it. I’ll probably add an answer on Sunday on how to do it so others can see